# Bootstrap 3 - printing colors on progress bars?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Anybody figured out how to print the colors on progress bars in bootstrap 3?  Saw some hacks for 2.3.2 but I can't do it on bootstrap 3.

```
.progress {
    background-image: none;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0;
}
.progress > .progress-bar {
    background-image: none;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0;
}
```

Maybe a starting point for someone, based off of some code I found for the old workaround.

Answer (score 1):

To build on the prior answer this is how I have the CSS setup to print from Chrome or IE.  FireFox still does not work.  You'll need to set up each bar color though.. info, success, etc.

```
        @media print{       
            .progress{
                background-color: #F5F5F5 !important;
                -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#F5F5F5', endColorstr='#F5F5F5')" !important;
            }
            .progress-bar-info{
                display: block !important;
                background-color: #5BC0DE !important;
                -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#5BC0DE', endColorstr='#5BC0DE')" !important;
            }

            .progress, .progress > .progress-bar {
                display: block !important;
                -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;

                box-shadow: inset 0 0 !important;
                -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 !important;
            }   
        }
```

Reference:
[CSS @media print issues with background-color;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893986/css-media-print-issues-with-background-color)

Answer (score 0):

Beside the  -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; for b.e. `.progress-bar-success` you will have to make the background visible also. You can do this by adding `!important` to the ccs rules, see: [Background color not showing in print preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14987496/background-color-not-showing-in-print-preview)

Add / bind the different print style to `@media print` in a different style sheet.

For printing the borders / shadows of the progress bar add `!important` to the border-box properties too. See also: [Remove shadow from printed version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804081/remove-shadow-from-printed-version) and [text-shadow and box-shadow while printing (Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975198/text-shadow-and-box-shadow-while-printing-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

This is because the browser doesn't print backgrounds (with default settings), but it prints borders and we can use it!
Just try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46216102/8601222

**Edited after comments**

You can add this for @media print (my LESS-CSS code):

```
@media print {
.progress {
    position: relative;
    &:before {
        display: block;
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 0;
        border-bottom: @line-height-computed solid @gray-lighter;
    }
    &-bar {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 1;
        border-bottom: @line-height-computed solid @brand-primary;
        &-success {
            border-bottom-color: @brand-success;
        }
        &-info {
            border-bottom-color: @brand-info;
        }
        &-warning {
            border-bottom-color: @brand-warning;
        }
        &-danger {
            border-bottom-color: @brand-danger;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Compiled CSS (with my variables):

```
@media print {
.progress {
    position: relative;
}
.progress:before {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    border-bottom: 2rem solid #eeeeee;
}
.progress-bar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    border-bottom: 2rem solid #337ab7;
}
.progress-bar-success {
    border-bottom-color: #67c600;
}
.progress-bar-info {
    border-bottom-color: #5bc0de;
}
.progress-bar-warning {
    border-bottom-color: #f0a839;
}
.progress-bar-danger {
    border-bottom-color: #ee2f31;
}
}
```

Works like a charm in Bootstrap 3.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17330380)

Comment: You're right. Edited, added a solution of this problem.